# Service areas based on time to travel raster layer in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, cost-path, service-area

I have a series of raster layers which contain values for the time to travel (in minutes by motor) to a series of health facilities. I also have the GPS coordinates of each of the healthcare facilities. I also have a raster layer which contains the values for the travel time to the nearest (minimum time to travel) healthcare facility.

I need to create a travel time based "catchment area" or "service area" around each health facility. Ideally, every pixel within each catchment area will be assigned to the healthcare facility it takes the least time to reach, and the catchment areas will not overlap, see image below for what I would like to produce
[image: where the red points would be my healthcare facilites, and the surrounding zones the areas within which it takes the least time to access that facility]

I have looked at the suggestion to a similar query [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/194580/service-areas-based-on-a-time-raster-surface-in-arcmap-10-1), and tried the Path Allocation Distance tool:

**Input source data:** My GPS coordinates for healthcare facilites
(the "source field" the defaults to my X coordinates, with no option to use the heathcare facility ID
**Input cost raster:** the time-to raster to nearest healthcare facility.
However the areas overlap as, see image below. [image: Result of path allocation tool - (distance_out) where values have been classified to exclude > 600]

What are the best tools and methods to use in Arcmap 10.8.1?

Comment: Cost allocation tool will give you that.